# Can't read stderr from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to start a child process and read its stderr, but so far, I can't read anything at all using subprocess.Popen, even stdout. I'm trying to use subprocess.communicate() to read from stdout and stderr. This is what I do:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('ls')
s = p.communicate()
print s
```

This gives me output (None, None). I think the pair is for stdin and stderr. Is that the case? Anyway, how can I read stdout and stderr from a process started with subprocess.Popen?

Comment: This guide to the subprocess module has a section that might be helpful: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/#working-with-pipes-directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the stdout=subprocess.PIPE and stderr=subprocess.PIPE when you create your Popen object:

```
  p = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

From Python docs (Subprocess module):

```
Popen.communicate(input=None)
```

Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

`communicate()` returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).

**Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, to get anything other than `None` in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.**